# PayPal IPN Listener - HTTP Response Code 500

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal-ipn

This error keeps happening on my website every so often. It's been working fine now for about 6 months but now decided to do it again.

I use 1&1 ionos hosting. The website uses asp.net and vb.net for the code. Its an online food delivery website which I set up myself by copying and changing some code that was written for me on another website. That site still works fine and is hosted with a different company so I don't know if it's something with ionos. When a customer orders, the payment clears in my PayPal but it doesn't tell my website that its cleared because the ipn is retrying a HTTP 500 error.

VB CODE TO CALL PAYPAL

```
    Dim paypalURLString As String = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" ' Live
    Dim paypalParameterString As New StringBuilder
    paypalParameterString.Append("cmd=_xclick&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("notify_url=https://bozzafodder.co.uk/IPNListener.aspx&") 'POST address for notification
    paypalParameterString.Append("bn=SlikkDesign_BuyNow_WPS_GB&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("amount=" & session("total") + 1 + session("deliveryCharge") + ddlTip.SelectedValue & "&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("item_name=Food Delivery&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("currency_code=GBP&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("custom=" & imgBtnPaypal.CommandArgument.ToString & "&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("custom=" & order.orderID.ToString & "&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("business=E4RYLU66FFE3L&") 'Live
    paypalParameterString.Append("paymentaction=sale&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("return=https://bozzafodder.co.uk/wait.aspx?orderID=" & order.orderID.ToString & "&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("cancel_return=https://bozzafodder.co.uk/placeOrder.aspx?msgID=1&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("rm=2&")
    paypalParameterString.Append("cbt=Return to bozzafodder.co.uk&")

    Dim displayParameters As New StringBuilder
    displayParameters.Append("showHostedThankyouPage=false")

    Response.Redirect(paypalURLString & paypalParameterString.ToString & displayParameters.ToString)
```

IPN LISTENER

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Post back to either sandbox or live
    Dim strLive As String = "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"

    'SSL Error Code
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strLive), HttpWebRequest)

    'Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim Param() As Byte = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength)
    Dim strRequest As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param)

    strRequest = strRequest + "&cmd=_notify-validate"
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length

    'Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    Dim streamOut As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
    streamOut.Write(strRequest)
    streamOut.Close()
    Dim streamIn As StreamReader = New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim strResponse As String = streamIn.ReadToEnd()
    streamIn.Close()

    Dim qscoll As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strRequest)

    If LEN(qscoll("custom")) >= 32 Then
        'Insert the paypal response
        Dim order As New orders
        order.InsertPaypalResponse(qscoll("txn_id"), qscoll("custom"), strRequest)

        If strResponse = "VERIFIED" Then
            order.UpdateOrderFromPaypal(qscoll("custom"), qscoll("txn_id"), qscoll("payment_status"))

        ElseIf strResponse = "INVALID" Then
            'log for manual investigation
            order.UpdateOrderFromPaypal(qscoll("custom"), qscoll("txn_id"), qscoll("payment_status"))
        Else
            'Response wasn't VERIFIED or INVALID, log for manual investigation
            order.UpdateOrderFromPaypal(qscoll("custom"), qscoll("txn_id"), "ERROR")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

In the attached photos you can see the errors in the PayPal IPN history. The ones that are SENT are from my other website which works fine on a different website. The IPN code is the same though, I've compared the 2.

[image: PayPal IPN History]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Your IPN listener is "Unable to connect to the remote server" when attempting to verify an IPN, and so returns a 500 HTTP status.

Your IPN listener must return a 2xx HTTP status for the IPN to be marked as successfully received. PayPal will retry up to ~20 times until this happens, and then mark the IPN as failed if there is still no 2xx success response from your listener.

Since the error is "Unable to connect to the remote server", that is what you must investigate and debug within your environment (listener code and server). Why is it not able to connect to `https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unsure where to go with that as I'm still just learning. The code has worked for months without any changes my end. Does it sound like a problem with ionos? Maybe a certificate or something has changed? Or could something have changed PayPal's end?

Comment: Impossible to say really, you need to debug the connection. Why is it not connecting?